# .rprofile not source when creating RStudio project

Tags: r, rstudio, rprofile, renviron

In Windows 7, I have my .Rprofile in a custom location (not `R_HOME`, not `HOME`). I informed the OS of this location via the user environment variable `R_ENVIRON_USER` pointing to this location. There is no other .Rprofile anywhere else.

[image: environment variable]

In RStudio, I set the default working directory (when not in a project) to this same location

When **not** in a project, the .Rprofile is properly sourced. However, when inside another project or when creating a new one, the .Rprofile is **not sourced**.

How do I ensure, that my .RProfile is properly sourced even inside projects (assuming there is no project-specific .RProfile inside the project dir)? I thought the environment variable would take care of that.

## Answer & Update

I had to set the environment variable `R_PROFILE_USER` and provide the full path and filename of the .Rprofile. In a command prompt, I typed:

`SETX R_PROFILE_USER "C:\Users\tspeidel\OneDrive\.Rprofile"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand what `R_ENVIRON_USER` is for; it sets a value to source an (optional) `.Renviron` file for the user from the location it provies.

It does not affect what the system thinks your home directory is.  That is still governed by `HOME` which you set on Windows with the same UI. And you can't just substitute `R_HOME` for it.

You can however read very carefully what R tells you about its process in `help(Startup)`.  Which is, as often, somewhat dense and terse but it does get to the real meat.  In short, I think you may want to use *another* variable to point to *alternate Rprofile*.

None of this has anything to do with RStudio which, after all, just calls R for  you (and cannot, as a running process, alter `HOME`).

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't clear to me I had to add the filename to the environment path, besides not using the correct variable.  `SETX R_PROFILE_USER "C:\Users\tspeidel\OneDrive\.Rprofile"` in a command prompt fixed the problem